# Floating helper dialogue

Tags: c#, android, ios, windows-phone-8, xamarin

So far I've been unable to find an answer to my question. I might be blind, or just Googling the completely wrong words, I don't know, but here's the question.

In many apps (Both on iPhone and Android) they have these floating tips that assists the user in using the app. For instance "Touch here to open notifications", and "Touch here to access settings", etc.

Now I'm looking for a solution that would hopefully work for both iPhone, Android and Windows Phone, but an answer to any one platform would be appreciated nonetheless, as I'll presumably be able to translate it into the respective Xamarin code.

Mockup (Taken from some other thread here on SO, that was never answered)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want a tip floating on your view you may use PopUpWindow in android. It pretty easy to implement as well